# Different between :nth-child(-n+3) and :nth-child(3-n)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I just found `:nth-child(3-n)` can't do the same thing with `:nth-child(-n+3)`.

I can use `li:nth-child(-n+3)` to select the first three li elements but I can't do the same thing using `li:nth-child(3-n)`.

What's the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), the formula format in the nth-child pseudo-class must be strictly in the form of An+B,  B+An is not supported.

An+B is actually a formal notation in the document: [An+B notation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#anb)

You can see the older non-draft version of the document, this part is more or less the same